# Azure SDK for php blob download causes out of memory

Tags: php, azure, out-of-memory, azure-blob-storage

I'm using the Azure blob storage to store huge pdf and zip files in the cloud.
I'm accessing the files through the azure sdk for php and pushing the files directly to the user (of course the user should not see where the file is coming from, so I don't redirect him to a Microsoft url).
My code looks like this:

```
$blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($this->azureConfig['connectionString']);

$blob = $blobRestProxy->getBlob($container, $blobName);
$properties = $blobRestProxy->getBlobProperties($container, $blobName);

$size = $properties->getProperties()->getContentLength();
$mime = $properties->getProperties()->getContentType();
$stream = $blob->getContentStream();

header("Pragma:no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Content-type: $mime");
header("Content-length: $size");

fpassthru($stream);
```

For small files, no problem at all, for bigger files, I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 93323264) (tried to allocate 254826985 bytes) in \vendors\azure-sdk-for-php\WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\Utilities.php on line 450
```

Is there a better way to provide cloud stored files to users with php without them recognizing it?

I already found this discussion https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/issues/729, but the curl solution just don't work.

Thank you!

Best
Gesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my understanding, due to download the bigger file, the program consumes more memory. In this scenario, we can take those actions to overcome memory exhausted error:

1. Set the memory_limit value.

There is a PHP env configuration named `memory_limit` to limit the memory which can be allocated. We can set the memory_limit value in php page using the code:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","200M");
```

If you would not like to set the file size, you can set the memory_limit value as "-1", just like:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","-1");
```

Another approach, we can enlarge this in configuration file (like php.ini). This [official guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/) tells you how to configure PHP environment.

2. Download file in chucks

We also can download large blob in chucks to reduce the memory overhead.

To see SDK source code in `BlobRestProxy.php`, there is a function used to get Blob `public function getBlob($container, $blob, $options = null)`, we can set additional param into `$options` to get the Blob in pieces every time. Here is my code snippet:

```
$properties = $blobRestProxy->getBlobProperties($container, $blobName);
$size = $properties->getProperties()->getContentLength();
$mime = $properties->getProperties()->getContentType();
$chunk_size = 1024 * 1024;
$index = 0;
//$stream = "";

header("Pragma: public");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $blobName . '"');
header('Expires: 0');
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-type: $mime");
header("Content-length: $size");
ob_clean();

while ($index < $size) {
       $option = new GetBlobOptions();
       $option->setRangeStart($index);
       $option->setRangeEnd($index + $chunk_size - 1);
       $blob = $blobRestProxy->getBlob($container, $blobName, $option);
       $stream_t = $blob->getContentStream();
       $length = $blob->getProperties()->getContentLength();
       $index += $length;
       flush();
       fpassthru($stream_t);
}
```

Any concerns, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Hello, thank you for you answer.
The first option is not possible, I can't increase the memory limit.
I tried the second solution, but I get the same error, regardless how big the chunk_size is. I'm not sure why, maybe the BlobOptions don't work correctly.

Comment: Hi @Gesh, the BlobOptions indeed have its own class type which is `Models\GetBlobOptions` , and that also has explored some function to set\get properties. We can see the [source code ](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/blob/master/WindowsAzure/Blob/Models/GetBlobOptions.php). Of cause, to create the `GetBlobOptions` we need to reference a namespace first `use WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\GetBlobOptions;`. By the way, it well be better, if there are any error messages showing to me.

Comment: Hi @Gary, of course I added use `WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\GetBlobOptions;`. 
So the error I get is:
`Error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 254826985 bytes)
File: /vendors/azure-sdk-for-php/WindowsAzure/Common/Internal/Utilities.php
Line: 450` so the same error I got before.

Comment: It seems to have not been split into chunks. We can `var_export($option)` before getBlob to check whether the range is right in the loop.

Comment: The options look like this:

`object(WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\GetBlobOptions) {
 [private] _leaseId => null
 [private] _snapshot => null
 [private] _accessCondition => null
 [private] _computeRangeMD5 => null
 [private] _rangeStart => (int) 0
 [private] _rangeEnd => (int) 1048575
}

object(WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\GetBlobOptions) {
 [private] _leaseId => null
 [private] _snapshot => null
 [private] _accessCondition => null
 [private] _computeRangeMD5 => null
 [private] _rangeStart => (int) 1048576
 [private] _rangeEnd => (int) 2097151
}`

Comment: It's strange. Would you please show me your code?  It seems that the whole blob is called somewhere. Is that any `getBlob` without options devided in chunks that you forget to comment?

Comment: I found a bug in my own code that prevented it from working. Sry for the hustle.

Comment: *Call to undefined method MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\Models\GetBlobOptions::setRangeStart()* Use instead `$range = new Range($index, $index + $chunk_size - 1);` and `$option->setRange($range);`. Range being from namespace `MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\Models\Range`